# passing variables w/o using <form>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<a href='new.php?logi_jo=$_POST[jo]'>submit</a>

<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='logi_jo'>
```

is there a way of getting the the value of `logi_jo` and pass it to another web page? w/o using `<form>`

the first line of code is the link. and the the 2nd line of code is the textbox.. and then the value of that textbox will pass to another page w/o using form action. I decide to not use form `action="??"` because that link is inside of a form.. thank you for reading

Comment: Yes, have, with ajax request, for instance.

Comment: Be more specific about what you are trying to do.  Why don't you want to use `form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this simple task via javascript, ajax isn't necessary.

**Your HTML**

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='submitMe()'>submit</a>
<input type='text' style='width:50px' name='logi_jo' id='logi_jo'>
```

**Your javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitMe(){
      var val=document.getElementById("logi_jo").value;
      document.location.href="new.php?logi_jo="+val;
}
</script>
```

in news.php page fetch variable by `$_GET["logi_jo"]`

Comment: ty for help Mr. Sabin.. sorry my Sabin, but it is not simple for me. i dont have knowledge in javascript T_T.. just little knowledge in php and HTML and i realize it is not enough.. T_T ty ill study more so that ill help yah later

Answer (score 0):

AJAX to the rescue!

```
var logi_jo = $('input[name=logi_jo]');
$.post(
  'test.php', 
  { logi_jo: logi_jo }, 
  function(data) { // do something to the DOM }
);
```

Comment: where should i place this code? sorry i dont have background in ajax. T_T ty for giving answer mam or sir elclanrs

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to begin with this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp